# Is it a bad idea to rely on contracts only for exported interfaces used as dependencies?

Tags: .net, code-contracts

First, I love Code Contracts but I'm a little confused with one thought:

My class `MyClass` uses a dependency being an interface `IDependency` for which contract class (`internal abstract class IDependencyContracts`) is declared and my class heavily relies on these contracts. I have no guarantees contracts were enforced for custom implementation of the interface provided by the client code.
As far as I understand I can enforce contracts only on classes in my assembly, but I have no control on client code assemblies.

Then must I use `Contract.Assert()` in code where interface is used to check whether returned result meets expectations?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. If the consumers of your interface is also using contracts they will of course thank you. If they are not using contracts they may mess up as see fit.

That's why I would go with Contract.Assume() in this case even if Contract.Assert() could be proven. I'd use assumptions for my own sake just as a reminder that others could violate the contracts.